# VSCode (OSX) replacing whitespace with %20 in href upon save

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using VSCode on OSX when opening a file that has a line like:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'composer:dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a></li>
```

When I try to save, VSCode alters the line by formatting it as such:

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="{%%20url%20'composer:dashboard'%20%}">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
```

This breaks the source code (obviously). How do I turn off this autoformat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line `"editor.formatOnSave": false` to your settings file.

You can also change this option with the new settings editor. Open it with `[⌘,]` or in `Code -> Preferences -> Settings`, search for `formatOnSave` and turn it off in the checkbox.

Also, check if you don't have some extension that is doing that formatting.